# How to use Tomcat 7 new aliases properly?

Tags: ubuntu, static, resources, tomcat7, aliases

Tomcat 7 provide new aliases that allow to store static content outside the WAR File. 
I found some instructions how to do that in http://www.developer.com/java/web/article.php/3904871/Top-7-Features-in-Tomcat-7-The-New-and-the-Improved.htm part 4.

But it does not work for me.

I have two context XML files. One for my application (admin.xml) and one for my static resources (uploads.xml).

I did everything like mentioned in this tutorial but Tomcat does not see any static resources outside WAR file.

My static resources structure:

```
/home/user/admin-images/-
                   -234bF5_image/image.jpg
                   -572d44_otherImage/otherImage.jpg
                   -12A4uR_otherImage/otherImage.jpg
```

admin.xml:

```
<Context path="/admin" 
        docBase="path/to/application/target" reloadable="false">
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Manager pathname="admin" />
</Context>
```

uploads.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/admin" aliases="/images=/home/user/admin-images">

</Context>
```

After context deploy images not reachable:

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/images/234bF5_image/image.jpg
```

when I try to reach this I get error that image can not be displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not manage to get it working. But I found another solution to serve static images outside web application.

You need define context in server.xml inside Tomcat configuration:

server.xml (this have to go into 'Host' tag):

```
...
...
<Host>
    ...
    ...
    <Context docBase="/home/user/admin-images/" path="/images" />
    ...
    ...
</Host>
...
...
```

That way I am able to reach static images like that:
[http://localhost:8080/admin/images/234bF5_image/image.jpg]

My new question would be:
**This way to share static resources is safe? Does it have any disadvantages?**

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get aliases to work with this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context aliases="/the_alias_path=/path/to/a/file/or/folder/on/your/disk,another_alias_path=/path/to/another/file/or/folder/on/your/disk" antiJARLocking="true" path="/your/app/context"/>
```

Comment: Warning: this is now incorrect in Tomcat 8 http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-8.html